# Get Sharepoint 2010 Calendar to show Resources

Tags: resources

How do I get SharePoint Calendar to show the available resources?

I have followed a few guides, and all make reference to a "Resources"' list, which may need to be create. So I created a custom List called "Resources" but the items do not display in the Resources section of the calendar, nor in its groups.
How in this Resources list do I create resource groups and have them display in the calendar or any other part of SharePoint?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am havign issues with this also... I done all the above but my Events are not showing in the Calendar. Can someone assist? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Remove the "Resources" list you've created
- Turn on the Site Feature "Group Work Lists"
- Go to your calendar ==> List Settings ==> Title, description and navigation ==> Turn on "Use this calendar for Resource Reservation?"

Comment: I have no option for "Group Work List". I only have "Group Work Site"

Comment: A group work site will have the lists ready to use. But if you need it as part of another site, then you can activate the feature at `Site Actions` ==> `Site Settings` ==> `Manage Site Features` and click `Activate` next fo `Group Work Lists`

Comment: Thanks for that.
How would I then allow access of this resource list to the default Calendar? I have created a resource group, and an item within that.